# How to iterate through column names in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to iterate through column names of an SQL to apply some dynamic query. However, I have a problem to iterate on these column names.

I always have an error saying *Usually a PL/SQL compilation error*.

The code is the following one:

SQL Code:

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR c IS
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_COL_COMMENTS WHERE table_name='my_table_name';
 BEGIN
     FOR current_field IN c LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(current_field);
         ...Dynamic SELECT QUERY
         new_string = new_string || ',' || current_field;
         dbms_output.put_line(new_string);
     END LOOP;
 END;
```

The final goal is to count the number of observations I have each time I add a new field in the sql query and save its result.

Pseudo code:

```
current string = ''
result = array(len(all_field))
for current_field in all_field:
   result[idx] = SQL_QUERY(current_string)
   current_string = current_string + ',' + current_field
```

Comment: You haven't defined `new_string`; but what is `...Dynamic SELECT QUERY` actually doing? And what other errors do you see alongside the ORA-06550 "Usually a PL/SQL compilation error." message?

Comment: Two things. Do you mean to be using ALL_TAB_COMMENTS? It works, but I believe a better choice is to use ALL_TAB_COLUMNS OR USER_TAB_COLUMNS. 

Whenever using a dictionary view that begins with "ALL", always specify the owner. You are going to run into trouble if another schema has a table by the same name. Better yet, if you are strictly using your own schema, specify USER instead of ALL. User views do not have an owner field as they only return records for the current user.

Comment: The ... Dynamic SELECT Query essentially group columns by `new_string` and count the number of lines. I am iterating through the columns and by doing so I can measure a potential  value deviation  some columns since the number of lines will increase. Normally for all row that have the same ID all values should be the same but it is not the case and I need to spot variables that are not replicated correctly. the query have the following form `SELECT COUNT(*) As "AGG_" FROM (SELECT new_string FROM my_table GROUP BY new_string)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set echo on
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
 new_string varchar2(250);
 CURSOR c IS
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_COL_COMMENTS WHERE table_name='mytablename';
BEGIN
  FOR current_field IN c LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(current_field.column_name);
      new_string := new_string || ',' || current_field.column_name;
      dbms_output.put_line(new_string);
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but I usually make dynamic lists of column names using `LISTAGG`:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER);

SELECT LISTAGG(column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) AS cols
  FROM user_tab_columns
 WHERE table_name = 'T';

COLS
A,B,C
```